# Empty block rule in Bison?

Tags: c, bison, yacc, lex, flex-lexer

**OK, so let me explain what I need :**

- I've got a rule describing blocks, e.g. think of C-like languages' `{ .. }`
- A block may contain `statements`, with the rule defined (rather obviously) like :

  ```
  statements   :   statement
               |   statements[previous] statement
               ;
  ```

---

**Now here's the catch :**

What if I want a block of code, or a `statements` rule to be also valid if it contains... nothing at all, or - to make it even more universal - to have a perfectly valid program which contains nothing.

Attempting to add... nothingness into a rule, quite obviously as well, results in like 100+ shift-reduce conflicts.

How should I go about that? *Most definitely, having the parser throw syntax errors because there is no statement, doesn't make much sense, does it?*

Answer (score 1):

**Well, that was simple after all :**

```
    statements   :   statements[previous] statement
                 |   /* empty */
                 ;
```

And fixed. No shift-reduce conflicts, whatsoever.

Comment: And here you see a major advantage of LR parsing over LL parsing. The LR parser has no difficulty whatsoever with this rule. Getting an LL parser to recognize it is quite a chore.

Comment: Actually, this specific example is easy to deal with in an LL parser -- just make it right recursive instead of left recursive.  The real advantage or LR parsing is dealing with things that are naturally left recursive (such as expression grammars), and cases where trailing context matters that can't easily be left factored, though some of those are tough for LR as well.